# linux sort commend result confused me

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I try execrise 'sort',but the result make confused.
I create two file
one is named `a2.txt`,the content is

```
aa
a
a1
```

and I type

```
sort -k 1 a2.txt
```

the result is

```
a
a1
aa
```

ok, all is normal,
and then, I create other file named `a.txt`, content is

```
a1 b1b c1c d1d
aa bb cc dd
ds dsa SD DSA
a b c d
```

and I code

```
sort -k 1 a.txt
```

the result is

```
a1 b1b c1c d1d
aa bb cc dd
a b c d
ds dsa SD DSA
```

my question is, why a b c d is the 3th? I think it should in 1th like result of `a2.txt`.
please give some explation of it,appreciate for your help and suggection anyway,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from `man sort`:

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start  a  key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of
          line).  See POS syntax below
```

(You don't specify `POS2` so the key defaults to the end of line.)

You'd get the expected result if you say:

```
$ sort -k1,1 a.txt
a b c d
a1 b1b c1c d1d
aa bb cc dd
ds dsa SD DSA
```

Comment: it means, it compare abcd ,a1b1bc1cd1d,aabbccdd,dsdsaSDDSA with "sort -k 1 a.txt"?

Comment: @user2245634 Your question isn't very clear to me.  Just guessing that you need the explanation for `-k` above: saying `-k1,1` tells `sort` to essentially sort only on the first field.